# Chome autocomplete on text input prevents keydown event from firing (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

When navigating to an autocomplete option with the keyboard and hitting [enter], other browsers (ex: Firefox 14.0.1) fire this event, but chrome (21.0.1180.60 m) does not. I'm using jquery to hook the event:

```
    $('input').keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            var $txt = $(this);
            //settimeout req. for firefox to append autocomplete
            setTimeout(function () {
                //**chrome doesn't get here until you hit enter a second time
            }, 0);

        }
   });​
```

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/a9vbe/4/

Anybody know what's going on here or what a possible solution might be? Using the keyup event instead would 'fix' the issue, because computers are faster than fingers, but I would rather not do that. Keydown (or Keypress) are preferable.

Comment: Works on chrome for me but I will check my version.- 21.0.1180.60 m

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644896/keydown-event-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: Thanks! @muthu , I think it's probably different enough to warrant its own question, since mine relates specifically to text inputs and autocomplete vs key event timing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with doing keyup in an instance like this, especially since it fixes the issue. The problem is the data-list doesn't populate the textbox fast enough for the keydown event to fire off the event on the input. At that point you are still focused within the datalist itself.  This is a prime example of one of the benefits of keyup.

Not to mention it will fire off autocomplete once the user releases a key, so you don't have it firing *1000x* because someone holds down the 'F' key for no reason.

**In ajax / autocomplete situations like this I always use "keyup".**

Comment: Thanks for the response; this should be acceptable. My original thought was that I should pick up the event as soon as possible since I'm submitting something to the server if they've hit enter - and I think it's basically "too late" to change your mind if the key is already down... but that's sort of irrational, and for the one person in a billion who is actually sitting on the enter key for a significant amount of time... well... whatever. Also, I'll try to upvote you as soon as I get enough reputation lol.